# Internationalize forms in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

In my excel file i have some macro's that use forms. Now i want the labels, buttons, etc translated depending on the user language.
I guess there is not something like resource files like in .net

but i'm not sure what is the best option to do this translation.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have a few versions serialized as XML files and depending on the user's language load up(deserialize) the correct XML and populate the controls

Comment: Can i include these xml files in my excel file/macro or do i need to look in the same folder as my exel file and put the translation file there?

Comment: If you want to keep everything in one file, you could create a  Select Case for the user's language settings that populates the controls based on the language selected. It might take a bit of manual input on your part to translate all of the controls, but it would keep everything together. It would also enable you to send the Workbook to someone else without having to send the XML files.

Comment: @asp8811 not a terrible idea but how would you handle for example chinese characters in VBE editor without manually changing language that supports those?

Comment: Good point. ASCII codes? Edit: I don't think ASCII can handle Chinese. Maybe Unicode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the current user language:

```
 Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI)
```

This will return a Locale ID based on the current user's language settings. To match this ID to a location and thus a language, go [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964664.aspx). You will need to translate your controls yourself.

How you then choose to populate the controls is up to use, but I would create a Select Case for the Locale ID and the languages you expect to encounter, with a default if you didn't include the user's language. It's a pretty cumbersome solution from a "I have to type in all of this stuff" standpoint," and I'm sure there's a better one, but it makes the workbook very portable and independent of any other files.

Comment: *You will need to translate your controls yourself.* technically you could use Google API to translate text at run-time but I think that would be far less efficient (and might not translate nuances correctly) in terms of performance.

Comment: I thought about that, using some sort of translator instead of just entering it in yourself, but your user would also need an internet connection. If you have the translations in your code, you can run the macro even if you lose your connection. Probably not important in this day and age, but something to consider. Great idea though.

Comment: I will go with this solution and translate the controls myself since only few languages need to be supported and there is a limited number of controls. I was just wondering if there would be a cleaner way than just doing this in code.